# Non static field initialization

Tags: java, collections, initialization, spock, lombok

My question is about non static field initialization using static methods.
Basically my code is

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class MyClass implements Callable<MyResultClass>{{

        @Setter private MyService service;

        List<MyType> myList = 
        Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<MyType>());

     //.... other fields methods and so on
    }
```

I find out during my spock test that `myList` is null after this statement (in every method invocation). I solved initializing it in the constructor but I cannot figure out why it's null. Can anyone explane me this behaviour and, if possible, give me some reference to better understand field initialization with static methods? 
Thanks

I agree with all of you, I don't understand what is going wrong here. I'm using lombok builder to create this Callable instance. I run a spock test like this into intellij2016

```
class InboundMessageListenerSpec extends Specification{
      private MyService service = Mock(MyService)

      given: 
      def myClassObject = MyClass.builder().service(service).build()
      ....other objects

      when:
      //stimulus that also starts the thread

      then:
      1 * service.myMethod()   
     }
```

The problem here is that when debugging this test i notice that it throws a NullPointerException when (in the stimulus method) it uses the Synchronized list that is null.

I tried replacing the builder with a normal instance creation and field injection and all works as aspected. I need to investigate on the behaviour of the lombok builder.

The stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.fw.adapters.secondary.NetworkInventoryDataAdapter.deleteCvlanRows(NetworkInventoryDataAdapter.java:111)
    at org.fw.kernel.flows.executors.StartMigrationExecutor.call(StartMigrationExecutor.java:114)
    at org.fw.kernel.flows.executors.StartMigrationExecutor.call(StartMigrationExecutor.java:34)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

line 111 is a foreach loop on the above list

Comment: Not possible. Evidence please. The initialization process is defined in the [Java Language Specification #12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5).

Comment: I tested , `mylist` results in an empty list when I new a `MyClass`

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your code so we can see how you are confirming it is null?

Comment: There's no way that can be null.  Full stop.

Comment: @passion An empty list is not the same thing as a null variable.

Comment: @Raffaele Restating your question does not constitute evidence. It is merely restatement.

Comment: I don't know which kind of evidence I can give to you other than the stack trace ( a simple NullPointerException) . Anyway the problem seems to be related to the lombok builder because when I create the object using the constructor all works as expected

Comment: I don't know why you don't **POST** the stack trace as evidence, considering that you've been asked for evidence, and that you've identified it as the only evidence you can provide. Instead of wasting time arguing about it.

Comment: @EJP Very well possible as the variable is not `final` and there's a constructor overwriting it. There's little point in using `@Builder` with mutable classes and the needlessly used magic backfires here.

Comment: @maaartinus There is nothing in that comment that is relevant to mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a well-known problem. You're using `@Builder`, allowing you to set all fields. And it does it. Try [delombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok.html) to see what's happening.

I'm not sure about the details, but it goes along this lines:
- your `@Builder` uses `@AllArgsContructor`
- you don't set `myList` in the builder, so it stays `null`
- the `null` gets passed to your `@AllArgsContructor`
- who copies it to the newly created object (*)

That's [issue 916](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/916). Not exactly a bug, just a surprising behavior. You'd better use `@Builder` for immutables only, where there are no problems and where you really need it.

---

(*) In Java, constructor's code get executed after the initializer expression.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your explanation. I used delombok and the behaviour is exactly as you described. Thanks a lot for the details and the links.